# Add column with results from applying UDF on two dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to add another column to a large dataset that stores the closest POID from that smaller CSV. I call two functions: the first to calculate the distance between any two points. This returns the ID of the POI closest to that location.

My problem is when I call the withColumn transform I get pickling errors like:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o41.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
```

sample datasets:

Piece of first file:

```
+-------+--------------------+-------+--------+------------+--------+---------+----------+
|    _ID|              TimeSt|Country|Province|        City|Latitude|Longitude|ClosestPOI|
+-------+--------------------+-------+--------+------------+--------+---------+----------+
|4516516|2017-06-21 00:00:...|     CA|      ON|    Waterloo|43.49347|-80.49123|POID      |
|4516547|2017-06-21 18:00:...|     CA|      ON|      London|42.93990|-81.27090|POID      |
|4516550|2017-06-21 15:00:...|     CA|      ON|      Guelph|43.57760|-80.22010|POID      |
|4516600|2017-06-21 15:00:...|     CA|      ON|   Stratford|43.37160|-80.97730|POID      |
|4516613|2017-06-21 15:00:...|     CA|      ON|   Stratford|43.37160|-80.97730|POID      |
```

Entire Second File:

```
+-----+----------+------------+
|POIID|  Latitude|   Longitude|
+-----+----------+------------+
| POI1| 53.546167| -113.485734|
| POI2| 53.546167| -113.485734|
| POI3| 45.521629|  -73.566024|
| POI4| 45.224830|  -63.232729|
+-----+----------+------------+
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("EQProject").getOrCreate()
def haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
  
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r
def ClosestPoi(rlat, rlon): 
    plat = float(dfPoi.collect()[1][1])
    plon = float(dfPoi.collect()[1][2])    
    mindist = haversine(rlat,rlon,poilat,poilon)
    for p in dfPoi.collect():
        plon = float(p.Longitude)
        plat = float(p.Latitude)
        rlon = float(rlon)
        rlat = float(rlat)
        rdist = haversine(rlat, rlon, plat, plon)
        if rdist <= mindist:
            mindist = rdist
            cpoi = p.PoiID
    return cpoi
ClosestPoint = udf(ClosestPoi)
df = spark.read.csv("DataSample.csv", header=True)
dfPoi = spark.read.csv("POIList.csv", header=True)
df = df.toDF(*['ID', 'Time','Country','Province','City','Latitude','Longitude'])

dfPoi = dfPoi.toDF(*['PoiID','Latitude','Longitude'])
df = df.dropDuplicates()
df2 = df.withColumn('CPoi' , ClosestPoint(df.Latitude, df.Longitude))
spark.stop()
```

Comment: you cannot call .collect() in UDFs.

Comment: I removed the collect() calls and passed the plat and plon to ClosestPoint within the withColumn transform and I still get the pickling exception.